Macro to change babel's caption for pre-defined sections for any language
So I came up with this handy little macro that in principle can change any pre-defined babel spanish caption:
\newcommand{\spacaptchange}[2]%
{
    \addto\captionsspanish%
    {
        \renewcommand*{#1}{#2}
    }
}

And it seems to work great, however I was wondering if there's a way to dynamically choose the language…
I've tried this using expl3:
\NewDocumentCommand{\babelcaptionchange}{mmm}
{
    \addto\captions\exp_args:Nooo#1
    {
        \renewcommand*{#2}{#3}
    }
}

Which I realize is quite hamfisted and only works inside the document environment and not in the preamble, I'm guessing that using a regular \newcommand or \def might make it usable in the preamble, but that's not the issue, what i want is to dynamically call the \captions<language> macro substituting <language> with any language of my choosing. Is there any somewhat simple way to achieve this?

As always, please don't post sniplet but full minimal examples that others can copy and test as is. Then it USA lot easier to see exactly what you're doing and see if you've missed something

Your command could e.g. look like this (be aware that end of lines can insert unwanted spaces so comment them out):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}
\NewDocumentCommand{\babelcaptionchange}{mmm}
{%
    \ExpandArgs{c}\addto{captions#1}
    {%
        \renewcommand*{#2}{#3}%
    }%
}
\babelcaptionchange{spanish}{\contentsname}{In Spanish}
\babelcaptionchange{english}{\contentsname}{In English}
\begin{document}
\contentsname

\selectlanguage{english}
\contentsname
\end{document}

but perhaps you don't need a new command as babel provides already various options (see 1.17 Modifying a language in the documentation) e.g.:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}

\setlocalecaption{english}{contents}{In English}
\setlocalecaption{spanish}{contents}{In Spanish}
\begin{document}
\contentsname

\selectlanguage{english}
\contentsname
\end{document}

